# Dictionary Parameter - Strong-type Key, Generic-type Value?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, generics

I'm passing a type parameter to a class.  I want this type to be a Dictionary with a key type of 'Date' and a value type that can be anything, as in the class definition below:

```
Public Class MyClass(Of T As Dictionary(Of Date, Object))
```

Where, in the above, 'Object' is another generic type that, when an instance of the class is declared, might be an Integer, String, Widget, etc.  However, the key in the dictionary must always be of type 'Date'.  For example, either of the following would be acceptable:

```
Dim classInstance1 as MyClass(Of Dictionary(Of Date, String))
Dim classInstance2 as MyClass(Of Dictionary(Of Date, List(Of Integer)))
```

But this would not:

```
Dim classInstance3 as MyClass(Of Dictionary(Of String, Double)
```

...because the Key type provided to classInstance3 is not 'Date'.

Alternatively, is there a way to do something like this:

```
Public Class MyClass(Of T)
```

...such that "T", for this class, will ALWAYS mean "Dictionary(Of Date, T)"?

I can't figure out how to get this to work - any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to mention `Dictionary` in the type definition anyway? You only need `Public Class MyClass(Of T)` and then a private variable of type `Dictionary(Of Date, T)`.

Comment: Thanks, great idea.  When I try to implement, as follows, isn't working for some reason:

Comment: So what is the reason after all?

Comment: Declaration code:

    Private Property localType As Type = GetType(Dictionary(Of Date, T))
    Private Property dictionaryInstance As localType

...produces compile error "Type 'localType' not defined" on the second line

Comment: Why would you want that? It's `Private Property dictionaryInstance As Dictionary(Of Date, T)`.

Comment: The class instance is implementing an interface.  In the interface, there are several properties that are must all be of the same type (i.e. "T" in one instance of the interface might be Double, in the interface we've been discussing it would be Dictionary(Of Date, String)).  So, I was going to put a property of type "Type" (call it "_typ") in the interface and then have the various properties there be of type _typ.  In the implementation we've been talking about, _typ would be set to Dictionary(Of Date, T).

Comment: You don't achieve anything by having a property of type `System.Type`. You only make your life harder and go against how generics work. If your class is generic `Of T`, and there is a generic interface `Of T` that your class wants to implement, and when implementing you want to use `Dictionary(Of Date, T)` as the type for the interface, then it's `Public Class MyClass(Of T) : Implements SomeInterface(Of Dictionary(Of Date, T))`. Otherwise I'm very much lost about what the problem even is.

Comment: @GSerg, you're the best.  "Public Class MyClass(Of T) : Implements SomeInterface(Of Dictionary(Of Date, T))" was what I was missing.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a second generic type that can be leveraged as the value type for your Dictionary:

```
Public Class YourClass(Of V, T As Dictionary(Of Date, V))

End Class
```

Then instantiante like so:

```
Dim objInstanceOfYourClass As New YourClass(Of String, Dictionary(Of Date, String))
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I thought of that but the whole reason I'm trying to do this is to only have to send one type as a parameter when the class is instantiated.  This class is also implementing an interface that only has one generic type passed so I don't think that will work.

Comment: A class can implement an interface that only has one generic type while having two itself.